# how do i view the system console for google earth?

Tags: google-earth

How do I view the system console for google earth?

The google KML Reference says that javascript "alert" statements are logged to the system console.  At the following URL, look at the "" tag documentation and its subsection on "javascript".  It says:

> functions such as alert() and prompt() will not be displayed. 
>   They will, however, be written to the system console, as will
>   other errors and exceptions.

I'm trying to find where this shows up.

I am working with google earth 5.2.1.1588 on a windows xp box.

I have tried starting google earth from the command-line and nothing showed up when my javascript issued an alert() command.  I also looked at the windows event log (both the application and system logs).

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

you can use firebug, you can see system log in console tab of firebug, you can use firebug lite any where

Answer (score 0):

On Windows you can install [DebugView](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896647) from Microsoft to see system messages from Google Earth in the output.